# Search for a value within an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have an array within an angular scope that basically contains an object within each iteration. I have used the **indexOf()** function before to check if a value exists within an array - but how can I check if a value exists within the object word value?

I want to use a foreach loop and just check if a word exists within the rules array in the format shown below - how is the best way to achieve this?

```
rules = [];

rules[0] = { word:"house"}
rules[1] = { word:"shoes"}
rules[2] = { word:"tools"}
```

Comment: `Object.values(o).some(v => v === needle)`?

Comment: [Please search before posting](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+search+array+of+objects), there are dozens of questions (with hundreds of answers) on the topic, your question is answered by at least one of them and probably several. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
rules = []

rules[0] = { word:"house"}
rules[1] = { word:"shoes"}
rules[2] = { word:"tools"}
rules[3] = { sentence:"horse"}

rules.forEach(rule => {
    if (rule.word) {
      console.log('Exist. Value:', rule.word)
    } else {
      console.log('Doesn\'t Exist.')
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i =0;i < rules.length;i++){
  if(rules[i].word === 'valueYouWantToCheck'){
   // do whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

Try this...:)

Comment: He mentioned in question, he want to use ```forEach``` loop.

Comment: @bharadhwaj foreach will serve same. just he has to pass index and item like rules.forEach(someFunction) and write function like someFunction(index,item){}

Comment: This is a working solution, I agree! But he explicitly mentioned he **WANTS** to use a ```forEach``` loop. That is the reason I notified you! Also he just wants to know whether such a key ```word``` exist, not comparing it with some value, I hope! Otherwise, it is a good solution!

Comment: @bharadhwaj yes got your concern.thank you for pointing that out.i will take care such things next time...:D

Comment: No offense brother! Just pointed out as I noted! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var rules = [];
rules[0] = { word:"house"}
rules[1] = { word:"shoes"}
rules[2] = { word:"tools"}
rules.forEach(function(item){
   console.log(item.word)  // your word of choice
})
```

You can also use `filter` function. If your required word is matched it will return the object or else it will return an empty array

```
var getValue = rules.filter(function(item){
    return item.word=='house';
})
 console.log(getValue)
```

Beside you can also use `.find` method

```
rules.find(function(item){
  return item.word=="house";
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rules = [];

rules[0] = { word:"house"}
rules[1] = { word:"shoes"}
rules[2] = { word:"tools"}

for(var i=0; i<rules.length ; i++)
{
   rules[i]["word"]=='valueforComparison'; // or rules[i].word=='valueforComparison';
}
```